# Is it possible to match on a function's return type in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to Scala, so still figuring out what the type inference system can do. Is it possible to do something like the below in Scala?

```
abstract class BaseBar
class DerivedBar1 Extends BaseBar
class DerivedBar2 Extends BaseBar

def foo[T]: List[T] = {
  <T type> match {
    case DerivedBar1 => getSomethingOfTypeDerivedBar1
    case DerivedBar2 => getSomethingOfTypeDerivedBar2
  }
}
```

... and then be able to safely call

```
val myDerivedBar1 = foo[DerivedBar1]()
```

... or

```
def getBar: DerivedBar2 = foo()
```

Comment: I think my answer addresses the first code sample in your question, but I'm still not sure what you mean by "match on a function's *return* type"?

Comment: I was wondering if Scala can infer the return type of a function based on the object to which it's being assigned. E.g. if assigning to a `List[DerivedBar2]`, could Scala infer the function type argument for me?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I updated my answer with my thoughts.

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion that I'd come to - thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match on the method's type parameter by "un-erasing" it with an implicit `ClassTag` parameter.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def foo[T](implicit t: ClassTag[T]) = t.runtimeClass match { /* ... */ }
```

As for inference based on the expected return type: Scala does use that context as part of its type inference, but I think you're going to have trouble getting it to do what you want here. For example:

```
def bar[T](implicit t: ClassTag[T]): List[T] = { println(t.runtimeClass); Nil }
val x: List[String] = bar
```

You'd probably expect/hope that this would print `class java.lang.String`, but it will actually print `class scala.runtime.Nothing$` because it's the most general choice to infer for `T`. I'm not aware of any way around this.